# Python For Loop documentation

Tags: python

Newb here, looking for some direction on the behavior of loops.

```
people_list = ['Tim', 'Dave', 'Ben', 'Ray', 'Aaron']
for index,name in enumerate(people_list):
    for x in range(10,51,10):
        print(f"{name}'s ID Number is {x}")
```

In the above loop, each name would be given every ID in the range. Instead I would like it to assign a different ID to each name.
Can someone please direct me to the documentation regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to give each name the next ID in the range, you can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) which allows you to iterate two lists together.

```
people_list = ['Tim', 'Dave', 'Ben', 'Ray', 'Aaron']
for name, idx in zip(people_list, range(10,51,10)):
    print(f"{name}'s ID Number is {idx}")

# Output:
# Tim's ID Number is 10
# Dave's ID Number is 20
# Ben's ID Number is 30
# Ray's ID Number is 40
# Aaron's ID Number is 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for, alternatively you can use a dictionary;

```
people_list = ['Tim', 'Dave', 'Ben', 'Ray', 'Aaron']
# assign an id to each person
for person in people_list:
    print(people_list.index(person), person)
# output: 0 Tim 1 Dave 2 Ben 3 Ray 4 Aaron

#create a dictionary with the id as the key and the person as the value
people_dict = {people_list.index(person): person for person in people_list}
print(people_dict)
# output: {0: 'Tim', 1: 'Dave', 2: 'Ben', 3: 'Ray', 4: 'Aaron'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use iter() and next()

```
people_list = ['Tim', 'Dave', 'Ben', 'Ray', 'Aaron']
x = iter(range(10,51,10))
for name in people_list:
    print(name, next(x))
```